# A question in corollary 2.5 Atiyah Macdonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Consider Corollary 2.5 below.

[image]

> I am unable to deduce xM=0.

$x=1+a_1 +...+a_n$ implies that $xM=M +a_1 M+...+a_nM$ , aM=M implies that xM=M but how is it equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi:M\to M$ be the identity map. We write $\phi = 1$ (viewing it as "multiplication by $1$"). By Proposition 2.4, there is an equation
$$1+a_1+\dots+a_n=0,\ a_j\in\mathfrak{a}$$
meaning that the endomorphism "multiplication by $1+\dots+a_n$" maps everything to $0$. Now, $a_1+\dots+a_n$ is an element of $\mathfrak{a}$, whereby $$x:=1+a_1+\dots+a_n\equiv 1\mod\mathfrak{a}$$
and for every $m\in M$,
$$xm=(1+a_1+\dots+a_n)m=0m=0.$$